# ExtJs Grid Multiple Same Plugins

Tags: extjs

Can we specify multiple **SAME** plugins(but with different initial config) for one grid? And what behaviour should we expect?

```
this.gridConf = {
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 1,
            listeners: {
                'beforeedit': function (editor, context, e) {
                   ...
                },
                'edit': function (editor, context, e) {
                   ...                                
                }
            }})
        ,
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 2})
    ]
}
```

Comment: I would assume it would either not work, or one would overwrite the other. What are you trying to accomplish? Whatever the end goal is, I don't think trying to configure the same plugin twice for the same component is the right approach.

Comment: I just have a piece of third-party code which i try to understand )

Comment: Ok, so what behavior do you _get_?

Comment: When i remove second plugin, seems nothing changed..the first plugin works as expected..

Comment: Try doing one as CellEditing and one as RowEditing. Maybe switching up one will get you the behavior you want.  I would do RowEditing on the 2 clicks.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. I've removed duplicate plugin from config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works only first plugin, others are ignored. So i've removed last from this legacy piece of code, and nothing changed.